# Testing variable of boolean type in Freemarker

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, freemarker

The `isOffline` field in my websetting object is a boolean type. In my Freemarker template, I need to check if it's true of false.

So I did the following, but it does not work

```
<#if !websetting.isOffline> false </#if>
```

It looks like Freemarker does not support the Not `!`. I've also tried `<#if websetting.isOffline == false> false </#if>`, but it's not working.

Comment: Do you have getter method for `isOffline` property? What its name is?

Comment: the getter method is **public boolean isOffline() { return this.isOffline; } **, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `isOffline` isn't the best name for a boolean property because the default getter method for it is also `isOffline`.

If you cannot change the name of the property then show that you want to call method in template with `()`.

```
<#if !websetting.isOffline()> false </#if>
```

But it is better to change name to something w/o `is` in front of it (e.g. to `offline`). Then you can use it in template.

```
<#if !websetting.offline> false </#if>
```

Comment: That's incorrect, at least without using some strange custom `ObjectWrapper`. `boolean isOffline()` (or `boolean getOffline()`) defines the JavaBean property called "offline", so you can access its *value* in FreeMarker like `websetting.offline`, without `is` and `()`. OTOH if your Java method is `boolean offline()`, then you will not conform to the JavaBeans spec and it will be a plain method, so you will have to write `websetting.offline()` in FreeMarker, with the `()`.

Comment: @ddekany: OP property name was `isOffline` with a getter `isOffline`.

Comment: Unless the OP has used `BeanInfo`, the property name for `boolean isOffline()` is `offline`, not `isOffline`.

Comment: @ddekany: What are you talking about? OP has class `websetting` where `private boolean isOffline;` is defined with getter `public boolean isOffline() {...}`.

Comment: Field and property are different things.